# UIScrollView in SwiftUI with dynamic content wrong length

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uikit

I'm trying to add UIScrollView supporting dynamic content to a SwiftUI project. My problem is that if the content changes, the UIScrollView does not update its length. In this example, the circles will get cut off. It's probably pretty simple, but I haven't found anything on this topic online. How can I solve this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var count = 5
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader{ geometry in
            VStack{
                Spacer()
                
                UIScrollViewWrapper(pagingEnabled: false){
                    HStack(spacing: 10){
                        ForEach(0..<self.count, id: \.self) { item in
                            Circle()
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                                .frame(width: 80, height: 50)  
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Spacer()
                Button(action:{
                    self.count += 1
                })
                {
                    Text("Increase Circle Count")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct UIScrollViewWrapper<Content: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var content: () -> Content
    var pagingEnabled: Bool
    
    init(pagingEnabled: Bool, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
        self.pagingEnabled = pagingEnabled
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIScrollViewViewController {
        let vc = UIScrollViewViewController()
        vc.hostingController.rootView = AnyView(self.content())
        vc.pagingEnabled = self.pagingEnabled
        return vc
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: UIScrollViewViewController, context: Context) {
        viewController.hostingController.rootView = AnyView(self.content())
    }
}

class UIScrollViewViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var pagingEnabled = false
    
    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.isPagingEnabled = self.pagingEnabled
        v.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        return v
    }()
    
    var hostingController: UIHostingController<AnyView> = UIHostingController(rootView: AnyView(EmptyView()))
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
        self.pinEdges(of: self.scrollView, to: self.view)
        
        self.hostingController.willMove(toParent: self)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(self.hostingController.view)
        self.pinEdges(of: self.hostingController.view, to: self.scrollView)
        self.hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)
        
    }
    
    func pinEdges(of viewA: UIView, to viewB: UIView) {
        viewA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewB.addConstraints([
            viewA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.leadingAnchor),
            viewA.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.trailingAnchor),
            viewA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.topAnchor),
            viewA.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no specific reason for you to use `UIScrollViewWrapper` you can use the SwiftUI native `ScrollView` component. This updates the view as required:
(Only this code needed)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var count = 5
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader{ geometry in
            VStack{
                Spacer()

                // Change here
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
                    HStack(spacing: 10){
                        ForEach(0..<self.count, id: \.self) { item in
                            Circle()
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                                .frame(width: 80, height: 50)
                            .overlay(Text(String(item)))
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Spacer()
                Button(action:{
                    self.count += 1
                })
                {
                    Text("Increase Circle Count")
                }
                Text(String(self.count))
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See here:

[image]

Comment: Yes there is a reason: In ScrollView of SwiftUI there is no way to do paging. I tried to do that with geometryReader, but I figured out that there is a bug in SwiftUI leading to a crash if the offset of a stack gets modified (animation) when the rotation of the device changes. So native SwiftUI is not an option (unfortunately).